# an integral involving product of modified Bessel function and Gaussian function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I encounter an integral involving product of the modified Bessel function and Gaussian function as follows:
$$F(r)=\int_{r}^{\infty}xK_{0}(x)e^{-a^2x^2}dx,$$
where $K_{0}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.  $a$ and $r$ are some positive constants.

I found a definite integral in Prudnikov, Anatoliĭ Platonovich, et al. Integrals and series: special functions. Vol. 2. CRC Press, 1986, shown as follows:
$$\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-p x^2} K_0(c x) d x=-\frac{1}{4 p} \exp \left(\frac{c^2}{4 p}\right) \mathrm{Ei}\left(-\frac{c^2}{4 p}\right),$$

But it starts from $0$.

I think maybe it is hard to find a close form of the integral $F(r)$, but can we get some asymptotic form of the integral in the form of, i.e.,
$$F(r)=e^{-a^2x^2}\left(K_{0}(x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}+K_{1}(x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{n}\right)\Bigg\vert_{x=r}^{x=\infty},$$ where the $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ are some recursive coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shall discuss the asymptotic properites of the integral when $r$ becomes large. Using the relations
$$\tag{1}
K'_0 (r) =  - K_1 (r),\quad K'_1 (r) = -K_0 (r) - \frac{{K_1 (r)}}{r}
$$
and performing integration by parts, we find
\begin{align*}
\int_r^{ + \infty } {xK_0 (x){\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x} & = \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2 } K_0 (r) - \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\int_r^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } K_1 (x){\rm d}x} 
\\ & = \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2 } K_0 (r) - \frac{1}{{4a^4 }}\frac{1}{r}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2 } K_1 (r) \\ & \quad\,+ \frac{1}{{4a^4 }}\int_r^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } K_0 (x){\rm d}x}  + \frac{1}{{2a^4 }}\int_r^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } K_1 (x){\rm d}x} .
\end{align*}
Continuing in this way, it is suspected that the integral has an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$\tag{2}
\int_r^{ + \infty } {xK_0 (x){\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x}  \sim \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2 } \left[ {K_0 (r)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{A_n (a)}}{{r^{2n} }}}  - \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\frac{{K_1 (r)}}{r}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_n (a)}}{{r^{2n} }}} } \right]
$$
as $r\to +\infty$, where $A_n (a)$ and $B_n (a)$ are polynomials in $a^{-2}$. Differentiating both sides of $(2)$, using $(1)$, and equating like powers of $r$, we find that $
A_0 (a) = B_0 (a) = 1$ and
$$
A_n (a) =  - \frac{{n - 1}}{{a^2 }}A_{n - 1} (a) + \frac{1}{{4a^4 }}B_{n - 1} (a),\quad B_n (a) = A_n (a) - \frac{n}{{a^2 }}B_{n - 1} (a)
$$
for $n\geq 1$.

To prove the asymptotic character of the expansion $(2)$, one may introduce a remainder term and show that it has the right order of magnitude. I am not going to pursue this here, for there is a simpler asymptotic expansion for the integral. Indeed, introducing the [known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E2) large-$r$ asymptotic series of $K_{0,1}(r)$ in $(2)$ shows that there should be an asymptotic expansion of the form
$$\tag{3}
\int_r^{ + \infty } {xK_0 (x){\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x}  \sim \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2 -r} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{C_n (a)}}{{r^n }}}
$$
as $r\to +\infty$, where the $C_n (a)$ are polynomials in $a^{-2}$. Differentiating both sides of $(3)$, using the asymptotic expansion of $K_0(r)$, and equating like powers of $r$, we find that
$$
C_0 (a) = 1,\quad C_1 (a) =  - \frac{1}{{2a^2 }} - \frac{1}{8}
$$
and
$$
C_n (a) = ( - 1)^n \frac{{(2n)!^2 }}{{32^n n!^3 }} - \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}C_{n - 1} (a) - \frac{{2n - 3}}{{4a^2 }}C_{n - 2} (a)
$$
for $n\geq 2$. It is seen that $C_n(a)$ is a polynomial in $a^{-2}$ of degree $n$.

Finally, I shall demonstrate the asymptotic property of the expansion in $(3)$. For each $N\geq 0$ and $r \gg 0$, we write
$$\tag{4}
\int_r^{ + \infty } {xK_0 (x){\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2  - r} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{C_n (a)}}{{r^n }}}  + R_N (a,r)
$$
We [know](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.iii) that, for each $N\geq 0$,
$$\tag{5}
K_0 (r) = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - r} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^n \frac{{(2n)!^2 }}{{32^n n!^3 r^n }}}  + \varepsilon _N (r),
$$
with
$$
\varepsilon _N (r) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - r} }}{{\sqrt r }}\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{r^N }}} \right)
$$
for $r\gg 0$. Differentiating both sides of $(4)$, using $(5)$, and simplifying the expression gives
\begin{align*}
\sqrt {\frac{{2r}}{\pi }} \frac{1}{r}{\rm e}^{a^2 r^2  + r} R'_N (a,r) = & - \sqrt {\frac{{2r}}{\pi }} {\rm e}^r \varepsilon _N (r) + \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\frac{{C_{N - 1} (a)}}{{r^N }}  + \frac{1}{{4a^2 }}\frac{{(2N - 3)C_{N - 2} (a)}}{{r^N }} \\ & + \frac{1}{{4a^2 }}\frac{{(2N - 1)C_{N - 1} (a)}}{{r^{N + 1} }} = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{r^N }}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $r\to +\infty$. It is clear from $(4)$ that $\lim_{r\to+\infty}R_N (a,r)=0$, whence
$$
R_N (a,r) = \mathcal{O}(1)\int_r^{ + \infty } { \sqrt t {\rm e}^{ - a^2 t^2  - t}   \frac{1}{{t^N }}\mathrm{d}t} 
$$
as $r\to +\infty$. By L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\int_r^{ + \infty } {\sqrt t {\rm e}^{ - a^2 t^2  - t} \frac{1}{{t^N }}\mathrm{d}t}  \sim \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2  - r} }}{{\sqrt r }}\frac{1}{{r^N }}
$$
and therefore
$$
R_N (a,r) = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2  - r} }}{{\sqrt r }}\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{r^N }}} \right)
$$
as $r\to +\infty$. This proves that for each $N\geq 0$,
$$
\int_r^{ + \infty } {xK_0 (x){\rm e}^{ - a^2 x^2 } {\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{{2a^2 }}\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2r}}} {\rm e}^{ - a^2 r^2  - r}\! \left(\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{C_n (a)}}{{r^n }}} +\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{r^N }}} \right)\right)
$$
as $r\to +\infty$. $\quad \square$

Comment: Many Thanks! just one quick question: is Eq.(2) valid for small r as well? or there is another expansion when r \goto 0?

Comment: And in Eq.(1), should it be K'_{1}=-K_{0}-k1/r? I think it misses a minus sign.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the second expression in $(1)$ and its consequences afterwards. It is unlikely that $(2)$ holds for small $r$ since the expansion is singular as $r\to 0$ whereas the integral converges. You could try a similar expansion in *positive* powers of $r$ but when trying to get a recurrence for the coefficients you will run into trouble. This is because of the introduction of $r^{-1}$ via the second expression in $(1)$. For small $r$, perhaps the method proposed in the other answer is the way to go.

Comment: thanks. can we use K_{1}=-xK'_{1}-K_{0} to substitute K_{1} in the first step of integration by part such that it gives us the positive power of r? I am trying to do so, it is promising but the details are still unclear. Or can we assume a similar expansion as Eq.(2) for the positive power of r and Differentiating both sides to get the coefficients?

Comment: if you read this paper: TABLES OF SOME INDEFINITE INTEGRALS OF BESSEL FUNCTIONS OF INTEGER ORDER, written by Werner Rosenheinrich. if you can check PP150, it expands the integral into an exp(-x^2) * polynomials which is positive power, but it is for BesselJ. so I am wondering it should be a way to do the same thing for BesselK.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(r)=\int_{r}^{\infty}x\,K_{0}(x)\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\,K_{0}(x)\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,dx-\int_{0}^{r}x\,K_{0}(x)\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x\,K_{0}(x)\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{4 a^2}} }{4a^2}\Gamma \left(0,\frac{1}{4 a^2}\right)=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{4 a^2}} }{4a^2}\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{4 a^2}\right)$$

For the second integral, hoping that $r$ is not too large, I should use the series expansion of $K_{0}(x)$ around $x=0$. It starts with
$$K_{0}(x)=(-\log (x)-\gamma +\log (2))+\frac{1}{4} x^2 (-\log (x)-\gamma +1+\log
   (2))+\frac{1}{128} x^4 (-2 \log (x)-2 \gamma +3+2 \log
   (2))+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Which means that we face two classes of integrals.

$$I_{1,n}=\int_0^r x^{2n+1}\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} a^{-2 (n+1)} \left(\Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma \left(n+1,a^2  r^2\right)\right)$$
$$I_{2,n}=\int_0^ r x^{2n+1}\,e^{-a^2x^2}\,\log(x)\,dx$$ are given in terms of a generalized hypergeometric function but they are not too bad
$$I_{2,0}=-\frac{-\text{Ei}\left(-a^2 r^2\right)+2 e^{-a^2 r^2} \log (r)+2 \log
   (a)+\gamma }{4 a^2}$$
$$I_{2,1}=-\frac{-\text{Ei}\left(-a^2 r^2\right)+e^{-a^2 r^2} \left(2 \left(a^2
   r^2+1\right) \log (r)+1\right)+2 \log (a)+\gamma -1}{4 a^4}$$

To make a test with $a=1$ and an expansion of $K_0(x)$ to $O\left(x^{20}\right)$. The given results are for $\int_0^r$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 r & \text{series approximation} & \text{numerical integration} \\
 1 & 0.285263415528616 & 0.285263415528625 \\
 2 & 0.334405994204032 & 0.334405994204095 \\
 3 & 0.335219550219573 & 0.335219550219654 \\
 4 & 0.335221360654815 & 0.335221360655037 \\
 5 & 0.335221361207574 & 0.335221361207882 \\
 6 & 0.335221361207597 & 0.335221361207760 \\
 7 & 0.335221361207597 & 0.335221361207876 \\
 8 & 0.335221361207597 & 0.335221361207860 \\
 9 & 0.335221361207597 & 0.335221361207854 \\
 10 & 0.335221361207597 & 0.335221361207905 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

According to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344518399_Series_Representation_of_the_Modified_Bessel_Function_of_the_Second_Kind_K_0_bx/link/5f7dd092299bf1b53e144421/download), there is a polynomial expansion formula  for $K_0(x)$ (have a look at formula $(5)$ in the linked paper). This would then reduce the problem to integrals $I_{1,n}$ at the price of a double summation.

Comment: Thanks! this is really helpful! but as you said maybe it does not work for big r. i found this paper: TABLES OF SOME INDEFINITE INTEGRALS OF BESSEL FUNCTIONS OF INTEGER ORDER, written by Werner Rosenheinrich. if you can check PP150, it expands the integral into an exp(-x^2) * polynomials, as the exponential functions decay faster so it works for any arbitrary r. But this is for BesselJ, i am wondering can we find an expansion in such a format for BesselK? Thank you!